RingCentral Ring-Out failing with internalError
I am starting a RingCentral ring-out with the below body at 2024-05-15T17:16:32.440534125Z
{"from":{"phoneNumber":"+19999999999,107"},"to":{"phoneNumber":"+19998887777"},"callerId":{"phoneNumber":"+18888888888"},"playPrompt":true}
and I am getting the below response
{"id":"s-999999999999999999","uri":"https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/9999999/extension/8888888888/ring-out/s-999999999999999999","status":{"callStatus":"InProgress","callerStatus":"InProgress","calleeStatus":"InProgress"}}
And then some time later I do get a session webhook notification with the party status: {"code":"Disconnected","reason":"InternalError","rcc":false}
Does anyone have any idea why I am getting an InternalError as a webhook notification after a ring-out request returns as accept/inprogress?
I tried different combinations and values for the phoneNumber, I tried to do not use the callerID, and using it. All of the tested numbers are real numbers, where the from is the ringcentral user extension, and the callerID is a valid RingCentral external number.
This works as expected on a different account.
